# Centering chapter/section/subsection and font size

Tags: chapters, fontsize

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}           
\geometry{letterpaper, left=1.25in, right=1.0 in, top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, includefoot}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amstext, amscd, amsthm, makeidx, graphicx, hyperref, url, enumerate, listings,multicol,capt-of,float, amsthm}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\newcommand{\doublesize}{\normalsize\fontsize{12pt}{25pt}\selectfont}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}


\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\centering ACKNOWLEDGMENTS }
```

I've tried using `\centering` and `\sectsty` but neither work with `titlesec`. Help please!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you try ta achieve is not entirely clear.  Could you add some details?

Answer (score 3):

Use either `sectsty` or `titlesec` to change the layout of the section headings. Here is a suggestion using `sectsty`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}           
\geometry{letterpaper, left=1.25in, right=1.0 in, top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, includefoot}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\allsectionsfont{\nohang\centering\normalsize}
\chaptertitlefont{\nohang\centering\large}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]