# Customise your own chapter style

Tags: chapters, titles, report

I'm looking to personalise my own chapter style as shown in the photo.

Despite a few articles on the subject I haven't managed to fully understand how it works and what needs to be done to achieve the following result. My document is a report.[image]

Comment: @MatDef try `titlesec` or `sectsty` packages. There are a lot of questions already on this site and tutorials on how to use these packages.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite easy using a configurable class like the [KOMA-Script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes `scrreprt`, which is another report class, or `scrbook`, which is another book class:

```latex
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrreprt}% or scrbook
\usepackage{libertinus}% use any scalable font you want

\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\huge}% Font of the chapter title
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\normalfont\fontsize{48}{48}\selectfont}% Font of the chapter number
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\thechapter}% Use just the chapter number without any prefix in the number line
\let\raggedchapter\centering% horizontal centering of chapter headings

\usepackage{lipsum}\setcounter{chapter}{2}% Only for demonstration

\begin{document}
\chapter{Methodology}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Several more configuration options are provides, e.g., to modify the spaces above the number, below the number and below the title. See the [KOMA-Script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) manuals for more information.

Similar things can be done using, e.g., `memoir` class or package [`sectsty`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306608/277964) or [`titlesec`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667678/277964). Please see the manuals for more information and ask a question with [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) if you have problems implementing your requests.

Comment: It still possible for document of type "report" ?

Comment: @MatDef Still? The original question did not even mention report, but only asked for a general chapter style.  Changing a question after it has been answered and thus damaging the validity of the answer is not exactly friendly. But, why don't you test it? My example also works with `scrreprt`, which is not `report` but *still* a report class. The examples in the linked answers work with both book and report or already show solutions using report. So your changed question IMHO is a duplicate.